# Get Term names from WP Term Object

Tags: taxonomy, array, terms

I created an array with this expressions:

```
 $taxonomies = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
 ));
```

And I got this as return:

```
Array ( 
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 79 [name] => Édességek [slug] => edessegek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 79 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 55 [name] => Ételek [slug] => etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 55 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[2] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 76 [name] => Glutén mentes ételek [slug] => gluten-mentes-etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 76 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[3] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 81 [name] => Heti ajánlat [slug] => heti-ajanlat [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 81 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[4] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 49 [name] => Indiai ételek [slug] => indiai-etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 49 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 55 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[5] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 73 [name] => Kedvenc ételek [slug] => kedvenc-etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 73 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[6] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 48 [name] => Krémlevesek [slug] => kremlevesek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 48 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 55 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[7] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 47 [name] => Levesek [slug] => levesek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 47 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 55 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[8] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 61 [name] => ph levesek [slug] => ph-levesek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 61 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 47 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[9] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 78 [name] => Saláták [slug] => salatak [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 78 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[10] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 77 [name] => Szendvicsek [slug] => szendvicsek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 77 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[11] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 75 [name] => Tejmentes ételek [slug] => tejmentes-etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 75 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[12] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 60 [name] => Új hűsítő levesek [slug] => uj-husito-levesek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 60 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 47 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[13] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 59 [name] => Új levesek [slug] => uj-levesek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 59 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 47 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) 
[14] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 74 [name] => Vegaséf max ételek [slug] => vegasef-max-etelek [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 74 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 ) )
```

I need to get only the `[name]` and the `[slug]` in 2 seperated array. How it is possible? I'm thinking about `array_column` and `array_push` options

Comment: What exactly do you want to look your final array(s) to look like? Generally, use a foreach loop, you don't need to use special builtin functions for everything.

Comment: @janh One array with only the names and one array with only the slugs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative using the handy [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/):

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
));
$slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' ); 
$names = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' );
```

where we *pluck* out the wanted field into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a strange thing to do, but I've seen stranger requirements, so I trust you have a good reason for that.

```
$names = array();
$slugs = array();
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
foreach($terms as $term) {
    array_push($names, $term->name);
    array_push($slugs, $term->slug);
}
```

Will create those two arrays. Note that I've renamed the variable you called `$taxonomies` as it's confusing to name it after one thing when it contains another (in this case it will contain terms, not taxonomies).